# Is it possible to separate .vscode/c_cpp_properties.json from source code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm working on a code base where we don't use VS code. So we don't want to check in .vscode folder into source control. But there's this specific part I do want to use VS code (and other people don't, so we still don't want to check in .vscode folder). So I created a workspace and saved it in the part of the source control where we store our personal files. That works fine. I can store launch.json and tasks.json files there and reference the source files using relative paths.

However, it looks like VS code only reads .vscode/c_cpp_properties.json from the same folder as the source file. So I can't check it in (and share with other computers I use).
I wonder if there's an easy solution to the situation? Thanks in advance.

```
/foo/bar/foobar.cpp
        /.vscode/c_cpp_properties.json

/personal/delingren/foo.code-workspace   <-- I'm including ../../foo/bar in this workspace
                   /.vscode/launch.json  <-- both launch.json and tasks.json work fine
                           /tasks.json
                           /c_cpp_properties.json <-- but this wouldn't apply to foobar.cpp
```

Comment: I don't get it. Why not just gitignore the vscode folder but keep the folder locally as-is? Why create this multi-root workspace?

Comment: Because I work on multiple machines. I still prefer those files checked in, just not alongside the source code.

Comment: ... checked in to what repo?